# Null is passed to todos_id while submitting form eventhough i've changed it

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-class-based-views

this is my view which is createview and i've used custom form and send current user id to the form

```
   class createToDo(CreateView):
        success_url = 'home'
        form_class = ToDoForm
        template_name = 'home.html'
        user_id = None
        test = 'vaseem'


      def get_form_kwargs(self):
          kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
          kwargs['user_id'] = self.user_id
          return kwargs

      def get(self, request: HttpRequest, *args: str, **kwargs) -> HttpResponse:
          self.user_id = request.user.id
          return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

this is my form

```
 class ToDoForm(ModelForm):
     todos_id = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'value':'test'}))
     title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':'title'}))
     description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs= 
     {'id':'description','cols':30,'rows':2}))

     date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type':'date'}))

 class Meta():
     model = ToDo
     fields = ('title','description','date','todos_id')

     def __init__(self,user_id = None,*args, **kwargs):
          self.id_data = user_id
          super(ToDoForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
          self.fields['todos_id']= forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs= 
          {'value':self.id_data,'style':'display:none;'}))
```

this is the post-data,from this data it is clear value is not none then what is the problem

```
Variable     Value 
csrfmiddlewaretoken 'QCBi8WL9GYK0LdRx1FQq7sXDNjSaKjjv8IWnLwQ63toz43uNhGtM1H8C50c54zUC'
todos_id    'None'
title   'test'
description 'testdesc'
date    '2023-02-23'
```

this is my model which is connected to my user moodel

```
class ToDo(models.Model):
    todos = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75,null=False)
    description = models.TextField(null=False)
    date = models.DateField(null=False)
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

this is the error showing, eventhough i can see the value in the todos_id input while inspecting

```
IntegrityError at /createToDo
      null value in column "todos_id" of relation "ToDoApp_todo" violates not-null 
constraint
    DETAIL:  Failing row contains (21, test, testdesc, 2023-02-23, f, null).
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to set the `user_id` value in `get` method, you can access it in the `get_form_kwargs` method like this:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
      kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
      kwargs['user_id'] = self.request.user.id
      return kwargs
```

Apart from that, your form override should not work, because order of arguments and keyword arguments is not correct. Arguments will come first, then the keyword arguments. Hence it should look like this:

```
def __init__(self,*args, user_id = None, **kwargs):
      self.id_data = user_id
      super(ToDoForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```